# java mapper ibatis error about return parameter

Tags: java, oracle, ibatis, mapper

I try to get the total insert count from ibatis by implementing `resultType="java.lang.Integer"` but it gives me an error. 
My mapper is:

```
<insert id="insertCarHist">
    <![CDATA[
        insert into CAR_HIST (select * from CAR)
    ]]>
</insert>
```

The error is:

> "BindingException: Mapper method 'com.xx.mapper.CustomSqlMapper.insertCarHist attempted to return null from a method with a primitive return type (int)."

Answer (score 0):

by using resultType and insert method as below you can get this error.

the solution found was removing resultType="java.lang.Integer and defining insertCarHist() element integer. void definition is also possible.

The aim of my work was getting the count of insert. I thought that, by java literature, giving result type would give me the integer value but it was given naturally.